# How to show metabox key to custom post?

Tags: metabox, post-type

is it possible to show all custom metabox key name and show it as dropdown list on my custom post with my custom metabox dropwdown list ?

> this is custom metabox from another plugin/theme and how to get all metakey
>   from all input form

[image: test]

> and show all of them to my custom fields name, my custom fields is come from my plugin that have custom post type function.

[image]

Comment: Please edit and update your question with more detail of the scenario you want so that someone get your question with full concept and answer with proper guidance. Thanks.

Comment: already edit and more details what my question is. thanks.

Comment: Why not you sneak pick the plugin code and try to find the code inherited for the purpose. I think that'd be the easiest way to get the code to do such. :)

Comment: and how if the user will add another plugin/theme that contain custom metabox and add value to that metakey from my plugin ? it's usefull if my plugin will auto detect all metakey from another plugin/theme. is't possible or not ? :). thanks!